# How can I make a mesh glow over time with keyframes?

Tags: animation

I'm working on a project for a friend and I am trying to get something to glow over time with simple keyframes. At the moment I am placing a keyframe of nothing different, then I'm moving the timeline cursor to the place I want it, then adding an Emission Material to it and placing a keyframe down. I don't understand what the problem is so if someone can help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

## Only properties can be keyframed

The action of "adding an emission shader" cannot be keyframed. That in not being recorded on the timeline.

When you add a node to a nodetree, that would be there for the whole scene. You can instead keyframe the factor of a mix shader ruling the shading of an object, for example between a transparent shader (so the object will be invisible) and an emission:

[image]

An alternative could be to animate the renderability of your glowing object by keyframing the little icon in the outliner. It depends on your project needs.

Comment: Replace the Transparent BSDF with what you want the material of the object's non-glowing state to be. Additionally you can just use an Emission node by itself and keyframe the Strength value from 0 to whatever level of "glowing" you'd like.