# How can I edit keyframes for shader nodes easily?

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

I am still pretty new to blender and I would like to animate some shading factors over time with keyframes. I was able to do that, but I can not find a representation of the keyframes in a timeline in a single view.

I got a hint here:
[How can I make a mesh glow over time with keyframes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87024/how-can-i-make-a-mesh-glow-over-time-with-keyframes/87025#87025)

Somehow my search within the Graph Editor does not work:
I would like to edit the purple nodes:
[image]

With this graph it is impossible to 
1. drag the selected keyframes alltogether
2. It is very annoying to have some many other keyframes

What I thought I could do:
Search in the search bar for `tire` to limit the view.

[image]

But somehow it does not find anything.

I would be super happy to hear your thoughts on how I could sucessfully edit the keyframes for one specific shader node. (Fac)
And also if it is possible to drag more than one keyframe after box selecting them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have a filtering option unselected. If you have "Only Selected" enabled, then only the selected objects keyframes will appear.

[image]

You can then filter down within the object by toggling the visibility (eyes) as per below:

[image]

Finally after box selecting the keyframes, just press `G` and move them all. You can also restrict to the X&Y planes as per normal, e.g. `G` + `Y`.

Comment: The `G` command is a very good hint,but the `only selected` option was already disabled (see it in my screenshot). I tried all of the filter settings but none would help me further..
Maybe the search is buggy?
Thanks anyway for your help.